# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified - pyspark

Tags: windows, python-2.7, hadoop, pyspark, pycharm

Geia!
I am facing a FileNotFound error on pycharm when runninng this code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init("C:\\Users\\user\\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7")

from pyspark import SparkConf 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Fresh-Fish')  
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

I've tried several proposed ways to resolve it but no good luck. I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/spark-project/spark1.py", line 8, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 280, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 80, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My system variables are:

```
SPARK_HOME = C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop  #hadoop folder contains bin folder and bin folder contains winutils.exe
PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Python27;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

I have also tried to point python.exe from a new variable on its own like:

```
PYSPARK_HOME = C:\Python27
```

Or even add specific paths to Pycharm Project Interpreter pointing to:

```
C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python
"C:\Users\user\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip"
```

but it didn't work

Two screenshots from Pycharm:

[Project Structure Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMG5x.jpg)

[Project Interpreter Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en2NX.jpg)

If you need more details I an happy to provide. I've been struggling for quite some days, any new ideas are very welcome!

Comment: You should be using Java 64bit, and remove spaces from all relevant paths to Hadoop and Spark. Plus you have downloaded Spark with Hadoop in it, so you didn't need to get it separately